# Jira query language for excluding issues based on current date

Tags: jql

I'd like to exclude issues who have a given status based on the current date, but can't figure out how to do it with `startOfWeek()` `now()` etc. Because those must filter on an issue field.

Eg:

```
AND NOT (status IN ("In review") AND now() BETWEEN (startOfWeek(-2), startOfWeek(1)))
```

Is there a trick that I can use to get the current time from an issue field? Eg some issue field that is aliased to now()?

Answer (score 1):

You most probably need `changed` operator. This will filter out all the issues with status `In Review` that were changed:

```
status in ("In review") AND status changed DURING (startOfWeek(-2), startOfWeek(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `updateDate` if you want to check for the issues that have been updated in that time period and are in the given status.

If you want to check for the date of the transition into this status, this is a bit more involved. Could you elaborate what you actually need to have happened in this time period for the issues to qualify if updatedDate doesn't do the trick?